# Why does $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{4}}dz=\sqrt{\pi}\ $?

Tags: integration

Why does $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{4}}dz=\sqrt{\pi}$$ How do you get there from the standard integral which equals $\sqrt{2\pi}$ ?

Comment: Substitute $u=x/2$.

Comment: What do you mean by: *the standard integral"?
Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral . Your case can be reduced to this one using pairity of the function and a simple change of variables $\tilde{z}=az$

Answer (score 2):

From the normal distribution you know, that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e ^{\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^2 \right)} \ dx=1$$

Thus

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e ^{\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^2 \right)}  \ dx =\sqrt{2\pi}$

Because of the symmetry of the normal distribution it is:

$\int_{o}^{\infty} e ^{\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^2 \right)} \ dx =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\pi}$

Now you can substitute $\boxed{x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot z }$ $ \ \Rightarrow dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot dz $ and you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

hint: $I ^2 = \displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty e^{\frac{-x^2-y^2}{4}}dxdy$, and use $x = r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta$